# What's the best way to export from Lego Digital designer to Blender

Tags: export, import, ldd

The Question pretty much says it.  My purpose is animation. I want the ldd model to be exported as individual pieces.  I've exported from mlcad before, and it exported as several objects for each lego piece.  that's a mess for animation.  I think I will probably need a 3rd party program for it as ldd doesn't export to obj, fbx, or any other format.  Which program should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that exporting a Ldraw file from ldd, and importing the ldraw file into blender using TobyLobster's LDrawImport addon worked really well.  The addon can add the word Lego on every stud, and it adds a bevel modifier to the object among all the other things.